# Low Quality Screencast with kazam and recordmydesktop?

Tags: 12.04, screencast, recordmydesktop, kdenlive, kazam

I created my first screencast recently using Kazam screencaster and edited it in kdenlive. But the quality of video is low, pixelated. I tried RecordMyDesktop, it is buggy and doesn't show a few parts of video.

Now, i don't know how to create a high quality or standard quality screencasts.

One more thing i would like to know is what frame rate(FPS) do you set while recording screen.

Comment: use vokoscreen ..

Comment: Alright, i just tried it. When i added the clip in kdenlive video distorts or get pixelated.